# How to calculate time difference more than 24 hours in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

Finding the difference of time which is more than 24 hours. As of now I am trying with time variable but it can show difference less than 24 hours.

Comment: Use an int that will hold the number of hours/minutes/seconds depending on the time resolution you need.

Comment: I am not clear with your answer. Please can you explain me with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to know the time difference between
`2017-01-01 13:45:00` and `2017-01-02 16:30:00` - in a resolution of minutes - so the desired result would be `26:45` (26 hours and 45 minutes), you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @From datetime = '2017-01-01 13:45:00',
        @To datetime = '2017-01-02 16:30:00'

DECLARE @Diff int

SELECT @Diff = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @From, @To)

SELECT  
        CAST((@Diff - (@Diff % 60)) / 60 as varchar(5)) -- Hours
        + ':' + 
        RIGHT('00' + 
              CAST(@Diff % 60 as varchar(2)) -- minutes
              , 2)
```

Result:

```
26:45
```

Note: `right('00' + <varchar value>, 2)` will add a leading zero incase the `<varchar value>` is only one char long.

Comment: I wanted with seconds too so I used DATEDIFF(SECOND, @From, @To). And did CASTing. Here is the code for CASTing (SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Diff/ 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((@Diff/ 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Diff% 60 AS VARCHAR),2))

Comment: Seems to be working fine. In that case, I would appriciate if you mark this answer as accepted as clearly it helped you solve your problem.